# Javascript Map getting values of sub in return

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue returning data from a mapping.

Here is the data:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name here",
    "description": "a desc here"
    "parts": [
        {
            "id": "432",
            "name": "part name",
            "stats": {
                "count": 4,
            },
            "description": ""
        },
etc....
```

And here's the current code:

```
var result = myData.map(function(value){
   return [value.name, 1];
});
```

What I want to do it to get the count so I tried:

```
var result = myData.parts.map(function(value){
   return [value.name.stats.count, 1];
});
```

But it's not returning the value of it.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `myData`? What is the value of `value`? It would be very easy for you to simply run the code and inspect the values you are working on (and determine what it is that you are doing wrong).

Comment: and what would you like to achieve?

Comment: tried `return [value.stats.count, 1];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map `parts` for getting the counts in an array.

```
counts = data.parts.map(function (o) {
    return o.stats.count;
});
```